# There are software to view a entity framework query result?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I would like to know if there is any software to manage and view result of a entity framework query like a MS SQl Server Management Studio for SQL.

Comment: i.e. you just want to output the query generated - to a `Debug.Print` for example?

Answer (score 2):

I think you easily can relay on  [LinqPAD](http://www.linqpad.net/EntityFramework.aspx) to execute, control and see results of the query.

There is detailed blog post dfined there: [.NET - New connection providers in LINQPad](http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET29)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is ambigous but here goes.

Try Debugging with a breakpoint to see the result of a Query.

Answer (score 0):

[Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) can show the result of an entity framework query. If I remember correctly it will show both the resulting data set and the SQL created.

See [Using LINQPad with Entity Framework](http://www.linqpad.net/EntityFramework.aspx) for a "how to".